# Differences about importing namespace in C# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm starting to learn C#.

In VB, when we adding a new references - in my case web references -, it simply type namespace followed by the class name to make a new object.
For example:

```
Dim obj As NamespaceName.ClassName = New NamespaceName.ClassName
```

Then I apply this concept in C#. So my code will be:

```
NamespaceName.ClassName obj = new NamespaceName.ClassName
```

...and it doesn't work.

Actually, is there any difference about Importing Namespace between those two?
And also can you give me a little explanation about Project-Wide Default Namespace Imports in VB?

**UPDATE**
My point is why "In C#, When I've typed NamespaceName, the ClassName was not listed in the Intellisense?".
However, it did well in VB, do I have to import something?
Maybe, there is something to do with the term "Project-Wide Default Namespace Imports". (CMIIW)

**SOLVED**

Answer (score 4):

In C# you need parenthesis `()` when invoking the constructor at the end:

```
NamespaceName.ClassName obj = new NamespaceName.ClassName();
```

VB.NET is more permissive and doesn't require them.

As pointed out in the comments by Anthony Pegram, in C# if you use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax, you don't need the parenthesis, you replace them by braces `{ }`

```
NamespaceName.ClassName obj = new NamespaceName.ClassName
{
    SomeProperty = "some value"
};
```

Comment: I think an exception that might be worth highlighting would be using property initialization, the parentheses become optional even in C#.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram, very good point. I have updated my answer to take it into account.

Comment: thanks Darin, but that's not solve my problem. Please see the update :)

Comment: @riandp, where is this class declared? Is it in the same assembly? If it is in a separate assembly you need to add this assembly as references to your project. Also make sure that the class is declared as public otherwise you won't be able to access it.

Comment: @Darin,
This is what i have done so far :
In VB : I added web reference from my VMware (web services/wsdl). then I put the code above. and it worked well.
In CS : I did similar things like in my VB project. but I can't access several class.
And now, i do think there are some limits about importing namespaces in C#? am I right?
if so, what's that? and can you tell me how to overcome that?

Thanks Darin, I greatly appreciate this :)

Comment: @riandp, so you have imported a web service WSDL which generated client proxy classes. You could try browsing the generated classes and see what's being created. It's difficult to say without more details about the WSDL.

Comment: Wow, nice post Darin. Seems like I'm not careful enough to differentiate between adding Web References and Service References. (haha)
Thank for the helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it as

```
NamespaceName.ClassName obj = new NamespaceName.ClassName();
```

Comment: thanks msarchet, but that's not solve my problem. Please see the update I've just forgot to put my parenthesis :)

Answer (score 0):

In your C# project, do you have a reference to the assembly where this class exists?  Different project templates may have different default assembly references, or you may have forgotten to add a reference in your C# project that you have in your VB project.

Comment: i'm sure i've not forgotten that.
Can you refer to my comment with Darin above? seems like I'll say a same thing to you, afeygin.

Comment: Are you referencing a service?